# tSendMail - New Line Trouble

Tags: talend

I am trying to create an email with the some job status information, which I wish to put across multiple lines. However, whatever I do, I get the output in one line. Have changed the MIME type to HTML, used "\n", "\r", "\r\n", String Objects newline. Nothing seems to work.

Although I noticed that these characters do get processed, even though the outcome isn't as expected. I don't see them in the email body, which suggests that the text processor accepts them. Just doesn't process them they way it should. Do I see a bug in the component?

I am on Talend Open Studio 7.0.1, on Ubutntu 16.04.4 VM, on Windows 10 system (if that helps).

Comment: You seem to have the newline character wrong. Try with "\r\n" (backslash instead of forward slash)

Comment: Sorry, I typed it wrong here (fixed the OP now). I tried the \n, \r and none worked. Anyway I got it working using the HTML break tag.

Comment: I was going to suggest you try that ;-) I'm glad you got it to work.

Answer (score 0):

HTML < BR > works.

I tried it earlier but looks like I didn't structure my html tags well so it failed. Did it from start and got it right.

Guess what - The more you try, the more you learn. :)